# Анимация при скролле страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ещё только начинаю работать над созданием своей страницы. Возник вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке страницы вниз картинка также сдвигалась вниз, а при скролле вверх - наоборот?

Answer (score 1):

При использовании свойства `position: sticky` элемент прилипает к экрану при прокрутке, пока не встретится с границей родительского блока:

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.img__container {
  height: 500px;
  background: gray;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Текст</p>
  <div class="img__container">
    <img src="https://emojio.ru/images/apple-b/1f60e.png">
  </div>
  <p>Текст</p>
</body>
```

При использовании свойства `position: fixed` элемент позиционируется относительно окна браузера и при прокрутке остаётся на месте:

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.img__container {
  height: 500px;
  background: gray;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Текст</p>
  <div class="img__container">
    <img src="https://emojio.ru/images/apple-b/1f60e.png">
  </div>
  <p>Текст</p>
</body>
```